# When upgrading aurora database with Postgresql, is there a downtime involved?

Tags: amazon-aurora

When upgrading aurora database with Postgresql, is there a downtime involved?

I know, that there is a zdp, when using aurora 2.0.7 with MySQL, but with Prostgresql, i do not know. Is there always a downtime involved, when upgrading or is the a way not to have a downtime as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is downtime for Aurora PostgreSQL. Only Aurora MySQL supports Zero-downtime patching on writer (ZDP).